# Description box not rendering correctly

Tags: html, css

So i'm trying to make a description box with this layout:

[image: Description item layout]

it's supposed to be like a preview for an article like shown above.
so far this is my code

```css
* {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: none;
  margin: none;
  overflow: show;
}

.descripion {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  /* max-height:; */
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 10px;
}


/* fixed */

.descripion .image-cover {
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0%;
}

.descripion .image-cover img {
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0%;
}

.descripion .title {
  position: absolute;
  left: 90%;
  top: 0%;
  width: 100%;
}


/* fixed */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="descripion">
    <img class="image-cover" src="https://visionjams.epizy.com/favicon.ico" alt="Visionjams logo" />
        <h1 class="title">
            Visionjams is coming soon
        </h1>
        <p class="summary">some text </p>
        
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to keep it responsive but I can't seem to properly position everything, the divs seem to ignore the parent div and screw up the positioning. is there anything i'm doing wrong?

Comment: using position: relative and absolute is the completely wrong approach here. Either use Flexbox or CSS-Grid.

Comment: @tacoshy do you mind showing me this, I've never used flexbox before (mostly because it's difficult to use for me)

Comment: I made this quickly to you. Is this solve your problem? https://jsfiddle.net/ceosvf4t/

Comment: @scrummy, yes it does. thank you. can you post this as an answer so I am able to mark it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a flexbox-approach which works cleaner and completely responsive:

```css
.description-box {
  display: flex;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.description-box > div {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.description-box > img {
  height: 130px
  width: 130px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.description-box h1,
.description-box p  {
  margin: 0;
}

.description-box p {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: calc(100% - (2em + 15px));
}
```

```html
<div class="description-box">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300.jpg">
  <div>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Description</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

It works by delcaring the container as flexbox with: `display: flex;`. As such the image and the following element will put at the same line. You use `flex-grow: 1;` to fill the remaining space.

Comment: this is exactly what I was aiming for, the flexbox thing is kinda hard to wrap my head around. thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

Here you go

```css
.wrapper {
        padding: 20px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        border: 1px solid red;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 250px;
    }

    .leftimg {
        border: 1px solid green;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }

    .leftimg img {
        width: 75px;
    }

    .righttitle {
        border: 1px solid yellow;
        padding: 10px;
        float: right;
    }
    .rightMain {
        float: right;
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="leftimg">
            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCPc7.png?s=328&g=1">
        </div>
        <div class="righttitle">
            Type text here
        </div><br>
        <div class="rightMain">
            Lorem ipsum
        </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: dont use float for styling purpose. Its just for floating images within a paragraph. You cause varity of issues like aligning the title and the text to the right side of the box instead of next to the image. It also dowsnt work responsive. Flexbox or css-grid is the right tool to use.

Answer (score 1):

Your css contained an error:

```
.descripion .image-cover img {}
```

Here you specify the same element as **parent-child**. But this does not affect the construction (usual note).

Here's a simple solution using your code and `flex` rule.

```css
* {
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding: none;
    margin: none;
    overflow: show;
}

.descripion {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.descripion .image-cover {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}

.descripion .title,
.descripion .summary {
    flex: 1;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="descripion">
    <img class="image-cover" src="https://visionjams.epizy.com/favicon.ico" alt="Visionjams logo" />
    <h1 class="title">
        Visionjams is coming soon
    </h1>
    <p class="summary">some text</p>
</div>
```